# Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

The error occurs when executing ionic serve, or ng build, I have tried to delete the node_modules folder and to do npm install but it does not solve it, I have updated angular and installed a new version, just like ionic, I have created a new project 30 times and it keeps happening. It only happens in new projects, if I run one created a few days ago it starts correctly.

```
PS C:\Users\Diego Ruiz\Documents\Ionic\Test> ionic serve
> ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
[ng] - Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
[ng] ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
[ng] Initial Chunk Files            | Names            |  Raw Size
[ng] vendor.js                      | vendor           |   1.52 MB | 
[ng] polyfills.js                   | polyfills        | 336.74 kB | 
[ng] styles.css, styles.js          | styles           | 276.28 kB | 
[ng] runtime.js                     | runtime          |  12.60 kB | 
[ng] main.js                        | main             |   9.40 kB | 
[ng] 
[ng]                                | Initial Total    |   2.14 MB
[ng] 
[ng] Lazy Chunk Files               | Names            |  Raw Size
[ng] src_app_home_home_module_ts.js | home-home-module |  16.29 kB | 
[ng]
[ng] Build at: 2023-07-06T11:52:05.804Z - Hash: 61f55ddf07abee36 - Time: 12273ms
[ng]
[ng] ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/common.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
[ng] TypeError: C:\Users\Diego Ruiz\Documents\Ionic\Test\node_modules\@angular\common\fesm2022\common.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')
[ng]
[ng] ./node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm2022/forms.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
[ng] TypeError: C:\Users\Diego Ruiz\Documents\Ionic\Test\node_modules\@angular\forms\fesm2022\forms.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')
[ng]
[ng] ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2022/platform-browser.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
[ng] TypeError: C:\Users\Diego Ruiz\Documents\Ionic\Test\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\fesm2022\platform-browser.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')
[ng]
[ng] ./node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2022/router.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
[ng] TypeError: C:\Users\Diego Ruiz\Documents\Ionic\Test\node_modules\@angular\router\fesm2022\router.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')
[ng]
[ng] ./node_modules/@ionic/angular/fesm2020/ionic-angular.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
[ng] TypeError: C:\Users\Diego Ruiz\Documents\Ionic\Test\node_modules\@ionic\angular\fesm2020\ionic-angular.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')
[ng]
[ng]
[ng] × Failed to compile.

[INFO] Development server running!

       Local: http://localhost:8100

       Use Ctrl+C to quit this process

[INFO] Browser window opened to http://localhost:8100!
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.0.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "5.0.5",
    "@capacitor/core": "5.1.1",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "5.0.5",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "5.0.5",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "5.0.5",
    "@ionic/angular": "^7.0.0",
    "ionicons": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^16.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "5.1.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~5.0.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "www",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              }
            ],
            "styles": ["src/theme/variables.scss", "src/global.scss"],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:development"
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              }
            ],
            "styles": ["src/theme/variables.scss", "src/global.scss"],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "ci": {
              "progress": false,
              "watch": false
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "schematicCollections": [
      "@ionic/angular-toolkit"
    ]
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:page": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```